# Why is the first box in the second row not in the second row?

Tags: wordpress, css, xhtml

I've battled with a two column layout for a WP index and got it working.

However on this one site it will not work:

http://justbedroomdesigns.com

You will notice that the third box containing a pic of a bed (or the first box in the second row - bottom left one) is not in its correct place (to the left of the final box with a bed pic).

I've used height auto to try fix it but it's still out of place.

All help hugely appreciated as is all the help I get from this awesome community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is that your images height is not same so give height to your `post-block` DIV. Like this:

```
.post-block{
 height:355px;
}
```

Comment: when I do this it breaks in Chrome?? Nothing is correct then. Is there an ultimate fix? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a CSS reset if you dont already use one. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ Using and calling one before calling your css file can do wonders with cross-browser consistency. May be a pain to add now being that after you will also have to change your current CSS again but as a last resort, should help remedy your issues. Also by adding the above code by @sandeep as it fixed the issue I was seeing in Ffox.